# Throughoutly though about some functionality of qt

Tags: qt

I'm new to qt, and i have a simble (may be pretty dumb) question that needed to be answer:
As far as i acknowledge, qt could be use to made applications GUI (probaly its most well-knowed purpose), the program i'm trying to code work like this: you enter the program, its show three boxs: enter, setting, exit (like those main menus we see in videos game). when we click enter, it will show the main content, or when we click exit, it quit. i am able to code the layout at which show the content of those choices, but can someone explain to me, does qt support the transitions between layout, like, how to do it, a key work would be suffice
regards

Comment: Did you try googling "Qt transitions"? There's plenty of docs and information out there.

Comment: It doesn't sound as though transitions are a must for your application, but if you want to see a good example of one look at this: https://doc.qt.io/qtdesignstudio/qt-design-studio-ebikedesign-example.html. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

which transitions?
qt have best docs about all things in that(except 1% of it)

[QEventTransition Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qeventtransition.html)

[Event Transitions Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-statemachine-eventtransitions-example.html)